# Add relationship required QField

Tags: qgis

I am currently developing a project in QField. Is there any way to make a relation field mandatory?

In the attached image I indicate the field that must be mandatory. The field is a relation that opens another form

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please note that using ALL-CAPS in titles is considered "shouting" and is likely to cause your Question to collect downvotes.